# UWP Windows C# App BackgroundTask

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, toast

I would like to create an application that use Windows 10 Toast Notification with Pushbullet API, I saw on differents sites that I should use Background Task of uwp app but I would like to execute the background task manually. I sorry I haven't code now. If you have site or example, give me that.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean push notifications. By sending a raw notification via WNS you can trigger a background task. a good read to implement this is this uri: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview#